# failed to insert into table (php mysql)

Tags: php, mysqli

im writing a app that checks user status 
im using mysql and i want to have a table name check

this is my code :

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO check VALUES (?,?)");
```

i get error :

```
Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check VALUES (?,?)' at line 1'
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table name (check)

is a reserved word in MySQL.

**Surround it in backticks like this:**

```
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `check` VALUES (?,?)");
```

Answer (score 1):

**`check`** is a [`reserved word`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) in MySQL . Enclose it in backticks !

Like this

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `check` VALUES (?,?)");
```